# How can I load a Store by user ID?

Tags: 8, commerce

I am building a multi-seller commerce site, where a user can register and sell their product.  I need to display a menu link if the user is anonymous to "become a seller", where they are directed to log in and a create store form.

If the user is logged in, I want to display a menu link that displays "My Store" if they previously created a store.  To determine if they have a store, how can I load a store via their user ID?

I have been unable to find an example where someone can load a user's store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user ID is saved on the store when it's created. Therefore you can load it with code similar to the following one.

```
$store = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_store')->loadByProperties(['uid' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id()]);
```

That will load the store based on the currently logged-in user.